# How can i make a method to change the middle character of user input without already know the the word?

Tags: java, string, input, replace, character

Im pretty new to java and i need a method that replaces any user inputs middle letter with another letter. regardless if the user inputs "abcdef", "frogs", or "pizza" it changes the middle letter to "Q" if i wanted. Im pretty new at this so i dont know how to use arrays yet either. i thought of using **replaceCharAt()** and the **str.length()** but i dont know how to use them together with unknown inputs. any help would be appreciated.

edit: i have included my class and my driver class to show what i am dealing with. i need to change the middle letter of th user inputted **dnaCode** to "Q".

my class so far:

```
public class ComputerMicrobe
{

  public String name;
  public String dnaCode;

//***********************************************************************
  //perameters

  public ComputerMicrobe(String newDnaCode, String newName)
  {
   this.name(newName);
   this.dnaCode(newDnaCode);
  }// end perameters



//*************************************************************
 // default
 public ComputerMicrobe()
 {
  this("12345", "ABCDEF");

 }// end default

//****************************************************************

 // accessors
 public String getName()
 {
  return this.name;
 }// end name accesseor

 public String getDnaCode()
 {
  return this.DnaCode;
 }// end dnaCode accessor

//***********************************************************************

 public void setName(String newName)
 {
  this.name = newName;
 }// end name mutator

 public void setDnaCode(String newDnaCode)
 {
  this.dnaCode = newDnaCode;
 }// end dnaCode mutator

//************************************************************************
```

My driver class (cant edit due to assignment):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
  String name;    //Auxiliar ComputerMicrobe name
  String dNACode;   //Auxiliar ComputerMicrobe DNA Code
  ComputerMicrobe a, b, c; // ComputerMicrobe objects

  System.out.println("Enter name of first ComputerMicrobe");
  name = stdIn.next();
  System.out.println("Enter DNA Code for first ComputerMicrobe");
  dNACode = stdIn.next();
  a = new ComputerMicrobe(name, dNACode);

  System.out.println("Enter name of second ComputerMicrobe");
  name = stdIn.next();
  System.out.println("Enter DNA Code for second ComputerMicrobe");
  dNACode = stdIn.next();
  b = new ComputerMicrobe(name, dNACode);

  System.out.println("Initial set of ComputerMicrobes");
  System.out.println(a);
  System.out.println(b);

  System.out.println("ComputerMicrobe a after mutation");
  a.mutate();
  System.out.println(a);

  System.out.println("ComputerMicrobe b after swap");
  b.swap();
  System.out.println(b);

  System.out.println("ComputerMicrobe c after reproduction of a and b");
  c = a.reproduce(b);
  System.out.println(c);

  System.out.println("ComputerMicrobe b after mutation and swap");
   b.mutate().swap();
  System.out.println(b);

  System.out.println("ComputerMicrobe b after invasion of swap a");
  b.invadedBy(a.swap());
  System.out.println(b);
} // end main
```

Comment: more code... show us how are u trying to do that!

Comment: No reason to pass the length since you'll have it with the input. What happens when you have an even number of characters?

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have updated my question if that helps

Comment: ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ i have attached my code

Answer (score 1):

first you should check the userInput paramter is valid, I mean it length should be odd and greater than 2.

```
if(userInput.length() %2 ==0 || userInput.length()<3)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("userInput length should be odd and greater than 2");
```

then you can do what you want

```
int middleIndex = userInput.length()/2;
return userInput.substring(0,middleIndex) + 'Q' + userInput.substring(middleIndex+1);
```

whole method should be like this:

```
    public String replaceCharaterAT(String userInput) {
         if (userInput.length() % 2 == 0 || userInput.length() < 3)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("userInput length should be odd and greater than 2");
         int middleIndex = userInput.length() / 2;
         return userInput.substring(0, middleIndex) + 'Q' + userInput.substring(middleIndex + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ;)

```
BufferedReader z=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String ch=(z.readLine());
        char valeur = 'Q';  //chat for replace
        String res="";
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length()/2;i++){
            res+=ch.charAt(i);
        }
        res+=valeur;
        for(int i=1+ch.length()/2;i<ch.length();i++){
            res+=ch.charAt(i);
        }   
        System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this..

```
public static String replaceChar(String word, String key)
{

    int length = word.length();


    int center = length/2;

    String before = word.substring(0, center - 1);

    String after = word.substring(center + 1, length);


    return before + key + after;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(replaceChar("abcdef", "q"));
}
```

Comment: Which is the middle character in `abcdef`?

Comment: Not really. there's no middle character in an even numbered word. Your algo replaces both "middle" characters but what does it do when you have "foo" as the word?